# One print statement outputs twice

Tags: python, csv, testing

I am trying to write a login module that searches a .csv file for the entered username.  If it finds the username it will the take the entered password and pass it through a function to verify it (the password is salted and hashed before being saved into the .csv file).

I ran the below code running through tests for the desired results for username that's in the list and correct password, username that is not in the list, username that is in the list and incorrect password.

```py
with open('userDB.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for field in row:
            if user == row[0]:
                psChk = row[1]
                if verify_password(psChk, password):
                    print('In')
                else:
                    print('Out!!')
            else:
                print('Out!!')
                sys.exit()
```

For the test with user in the list and correct password I get the 'In' statement printed twice and when I test for user in the list and incorrect password I get 'Out' twice.  While that is the desired result I just want to understand what's going on here.

When I test for username not in the list 'Out' is printed only once.

```py
def verify_password(stored_password,provided_password):
    """Verify a stored password against one provided by user"""
    salt = stored_password[:64]
    stored_password = stored_password[64:]
    pwdhash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha512',provided_password.encode('utf-8'),salt.encode('ascii'),100000)
    pwdhash = binascii.hexlify(pwdhash).decode('ascii')
    return pwdhash == stored_password
```

Comment: Show your code for `verify_password`. I suspect you have some print statements in that function.

Comment: Why are you iterating over `row`? The `field` variable is not used anywhere

Comment: @niyasc I thought I had to iterate over the rows, then the items in the row separately

Comment: Please use a debugger, e.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is this line
`for field in row:`

You are checking the username and password for each field in each row. Since you have two fields ('username' and 'password') in each row, it executes twice.

The fix is:

```
with open('userDB.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if user == row[0]:
            psChk = row[1]
            if verify_password(psChk, password):
                print('In')
            else:
                print('Out!!')
        else:
            print('Out!!')
            sys.exit()
```